# How to dynamically create an angular custom element into ckeditor?

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor

I'm trying to dynamically create an embed component on the fly. Basically, when a user clicks on a toolbar button I want it to insert the HTML for the embed component at the cursor position. All is well, except for actually getting the HTML itself.

This is the guide I followed on the docs

https://angular.io/guide/elements

under the subsection angular elements, maybe I'm using the wrong thing here. But if anyone has other suggestions, I would love to hear.

This is the code responsible for generating the embed

```js
    link(event)
    {
       const embed = document.createElement('embed-card')  as NgElement & WithProperties<{embedSrc: string}>;
       embed.embedSrc = 'https://github.com/itteco/iframely';
       console.log(embed);
       console.log(embed.innerHTML);
       this.myckeditor.instance.insertHtml(embed.innerHTML);
    }
```

This is the embed component itself

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'embed-card',
  templateUrl: './embed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./embed.component.css'],
  providers: [EmbedService]
})

export class EmbedComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input()
  embedSrc: string;
  embedData: any[];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private embedService: EmbedService
  ) { }

  getEmbedJsonData() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.embedService.GetMetaTagData(this.embedSrc)
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.embedData = data;
          console.log(this.embedData);
        }
        );
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmbedJsonData();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    //console.log("it got changed");
    this.getEmbedJsonData();
  }
}
```

and the accompanying HTML for the embed here

```js
<div *ngIf = "embedData.length != 0" class = "media embed-box">
    <a [ngStyle] = "{

                     'background-image': 'url('+ embedData.thumbnail_url +')',
                     'width' : '218.816px',
                     'height': '120px' 
                    }"></a>


    <!-- <img class = "embed-thumbnail" [src]='embedData.thumbnail_url'/> -->
    <div class = "embed-body" style = " margin-left: 10px;">
        <div class = "media-body">
            <h5 class = "mt-0"> {{ embedData.title }} </h5>
            <p class = "description block-with-text"> {{ embedData.description }} </p>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

And yes I do have the server running, so the embed metadata is definitely being received.

when I run it, innerHTML is null. And the embed-card object looks like the picture below

https://snag.gy/FjNDct.jpg

Update:

This really seems like something I should be able to find on google, but I've done an extensive amount of searching and haven't found anything regarding my issue. Maybe I'm just not searching right, but please if anyone can give me a guiding hand that will help, it's been 5 days.